# How could I retrive accessor name inside column header react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have columns as:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "name", // accessor is the "key" in the data
        },
        {
            Header: "Email",
            accessor: "email",
        }
    ])
```

and my table code snippet looks like:

```
<table
    {...getTableProps()}
    id="basicTable"
    className="table table-bordered action-table table-striped table-hover mb-0"
>
    <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <th
                        {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                        className="align-top"
                    >
                        <div
                            // {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                console.log(
                                    `col ${column.accessor}`
                                );
                            }}
                        >
                            {column.render("Header")}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {column.canFilter
                                ? column.render(
                                      "Filter"
                                  )
                                : ""}
                        </div>
                    </th>
                ))}
            </tr>
        ))}
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now, here on th, I am trying to retrive the accessor, but I am not being able to do so, on consoling, `column.accessor`, it returns:

```
function accessor(row) {
        return getBy(row, accessorPath);
      }
```

How, could I get the accessor name so that I could fire api call with col name for sorting?

Update:

accessor function looks as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keeping `accessor` as function helps in handling few other functionalities, for this usecase try to keep another key(eg. sortByBE) for that in column configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log(cell.value) , you will get the associated cell value.